# google map api v2 - first steps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am new in using google map api v2.
i do every thing base on this tutorial:
[Android SDK: Working with Google Maps - Application Setup](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-working-with-google-maps-application-setup--mobile-15771)

but in  5 :

> 5. Add a Map to the App

when i add fragment to may layout, i got some rendering error in my preview and show me stack overflow error.
and when I Run my code this i see this errors:

```
02-20 21:36:37.601  11893-11893/com.example.gmt3 I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 11893 SIG: 9
02-20 21:41:30.941  12732-12732/com.example.gmt3 D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-20 21:41:31.021  12732-12732/com.example.gmt3 W/ResourceType﹕ CREATING STRING CACHE OF 44 bytes
02-20 21:41:31.041  12732-12732/com.example.gmt3 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-20 21:41:31.041  12732-12732/com.example.gmt3 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41662d88)
02-20 21:41:31.051  12732-12732/com.example.gmt3 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.gmt3, PID: 12732
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gmt3/com.example.gmt3.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5137)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:718)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:297)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at com.example.gmt3.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:14)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2201)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5137)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:718)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 5077000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.x(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.F(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.E(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.ju(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4785)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:297)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at com.example.gmt3.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:14)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2201)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5137)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:718)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-20 21:42:01.901  13963-13963/com.example.gmt3 W/ResourceType﹕ CREATING STRING CACHE OF 44 bytes
02-20 21:42:01.921  13963-13963/com.example.gmt3 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-20 21:42:01.921  13963-13963/com.example.gmt3 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41662d88)
02-20 21:44:41.511  15098-15098/com.example.gmt3 D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-20 21:44:41.641  15098-15098/com.example.gmt3 W/ResourceType﹕ CREATING STRING CACHE OF 44 bytes
02-20 21:44:41.671  15098-15098/com.example.gmt3 I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: RGURRAM_AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.2.2_RB1.04.04.04.087.030+PATCH[ES]_msm8974_LNX.LA.3.5.2.2_RB1__release_ENGG ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.15
    Build Date: 08/12/14 Tue
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.2.2_rb1
    Local Patches: 8b00bd16f3c1d9d35a2fa902df5e679888d2b2e3 Fixes an llvm crash with mini dEQP apk
    38bad22e162dead4e008444520a0144c78a347bd Fixes a potential dEQP crash.
    ce345e1c45c2ae2d1fb2cb125c8d2574f1af5f95 Rev
02-20 21:44:41.701  15098-15098/com.example.gmt3 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
02-20 21:44:41.761  15098-15098/com.example.gmt3 I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@42e245d8 time:70662662
02-20 21:51:39.711  15098-15098/com.example.gmt3 I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@42e245d8 time:71080619
02-20 21:51:45.771  16948-16948/com.example.gmt3 W/ResourceType﹕ CREATING STRING CACHE OF 44 bytes
02-20 21:51:45.811  16948-16948/com.example.gmt3 I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: RGURRAM_AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.2.2_RB1.04.04.04.087.030+PATCH[ES]_msm8974_LNX.LA.3.5.2.2_RB1__release_ENGG ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.15
    Build Date: 08/12/14 Tue
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.2.2_rb1
    Local Patches: 8b00bd16f3c1d9d35a2fa902df5e679888d2b2e3 Fixes an llvm crash with mini dEQP apk
    38bad22e162dead4e008444520a0144c78a347bd Fixes a potential dEQP crash.
    ce345e1c45c2ae2d1fb2cb125c8d2574f1af5f95 Rev
02-20 21:51:45.851  16948-16948/com.example.gmt3 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
02-20 21:51:45.921  16948-16948/com.example.gmt3 I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@428164f0 time:71086820
02-20 21:52:30.821  18305-18305/com.example.gmt3 D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-20 21:52:30.911  18305-18305/com.example.gmt3 W/ResourceType﹕ CREATING STRING CACHE OF 44 bytes
02-20 21:52:30.931  18305-18305/com.example.gmt3 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-20 21:52:30.931  18305-18305/com.example.gmt3 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41662d88)
02-20 21:52:30.941  18305-18305/com.example.gmt3 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.gmt3, PID: 18305
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gmt3/com.example.gmt3.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5137)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:718)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:297)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at com.example.gmt3.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:14)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2201)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5137)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:718)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 5077000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.x(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.F(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.E(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.ju(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4785)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:297)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at com.example.gmt3.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:14)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2201)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5137)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:718)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

can some one guide me about this?
pn: sorry for such a silly q.
Edit:
my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.gmt3"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17"/>



    <permission android:name="com.example.gmt3.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gmt3.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyDg3mKRpkNhYeyxdrv2xjnkoS8mDt3qsmo" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error log

`The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 5077000 but found 0. You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

Maybe you have only forgotten to add this refference to your manifest

Comment: i have the key and i edit my post. u can see it in my manifest code.